# Which flash server i should use for flash chat with a lot of instant users?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, chat

I'm currently developing flash chat for social networking websites like facebook. Actually i want to develope flash chat in this game. Chat would have a lot of instant active users. So that, i need to know which flash servers i should use, is there any free ones that are pretty good for such high performance needs?

I've found [ElectroServer4 Professional](http://es-wiki.com/index.php?title=Main_Page). Is it enough for my task?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One free one is Red5 (http://code.google.com/p/red5/) I haven't messed with it in a while but it seemed pretty decent.

Comment: Thank u Chris Gutierrez, hope it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question a while ago: [Best Flash Audio/Video + Interactivity server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168114/best-flash-audio-video-interactivity-server)

I ended up going with [Wowza Media Server](http://www.wowzamedia.com/products.html), and have no complaints so far. I had bad luck with Red5, I would not recommend it.

Comment: thank davr, 
but it costs money =) one thing makes me happy it's more cheaper than others